# JAVA- Returning an Array to main

Tags: java, arrays

In the program I'm working on, I created a loop to receive 20 individual characters as user input, convert to char, store in array2, and return array2 to main.  When I ran the program I wrote, it seems that the code I wrote didn't store the chars in array2 properly.

In main:

```
// Create array to hold user's answers, and pass answers to the array.
char array2[ ] = new char[20];
getAnswers(array2);
```

In getAnswers():

```
// getAnswers method requests user input and passes to array2.
public static char[ ] getAnswers(char array2[ ])
{
   String input;  // Holds user input.

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Request user input.
   System.out.println("Enter the answers for the the multiple choice exam.");

   // Loop to receive input into array.
   for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++)
   {
      System.out.print("Enter number " + (index + 1) +": ");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();
      array2 = input.toCharArray();
   }
   return array2;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
array2[index] = input.charAt(0);
```

after you obtain the value into the input variable instead of assigning it a new char array every time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you're creating a new array2 with each input and thereby destroying any previous input with the previous array2 that you created.

If you absolutely need to create a char array, why not append the String answers into a StringBuffer object, and then when done, call toString().toCharArray() on the StringBuffer.

Myself, I'd create an ArrayList and just append the response to the ArrayList and at the end return the ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks! May I sometime return the favor!

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to modify the method param. You can try :

```
public static char[ ] getAnswers(char array2[ ])
{
   String input;  // Holds user input.

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Request user input.
   System.out.println("Enter the answers for the the multiple choice exam.");

String tmp = "";
for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++)
{
   System.out.print("Enter number " + (index + 1) +": ");
   input = keyboard.nextLine();
   tmp += input.chaAt(0);   // check length is > 0 here
}
return tmp.toCharArray();
}
```